# Code to remove role using command on discord.js (repl.it)

Tags: discord.js, replit

what code should I use to remove a specific role?
(I'm using repl.it and I'm new to it, there's no error, I just need a code. I have also tried doing this

`if(message.content.toLowerCase() === ">mcroleremove") { let role2 = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Flop SMP Members") message.member.role.remove(role2) message.channel.send('We may hope you to see again on the SMP!') }`

No error have occurred but it doesn't work when I use the `">mcroleremove"` command, even If I use the command, no errors have showed.
Thanks.

Comment: You made a type, it's ``message.member.roles` with a `s` nor `.role`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably didn't work because there is no role exactly named `Flop SMP Members` (maybe a typo or a none-trimmed space). Try using the role's id instead. It's much more efficient and useful ! (Or maybe you don't have the `GUILD_MEMBERS`)
First check if you have it :

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [
  "GUILD_MEMBERS",
  "GUILD_MESSAGES"
  "GUILDS"
]})
```

If, even after using that it doesn't work, then try fetching the role:

```js
client.on('message',async message =>{
  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === ">mcroleremove"){
    let role = await message.guild.roles.fetch("id of your role") 
    return message.member.roles.remove(role2)
.then(() => message.reply('We may hope you to see again on the SMP!'))
.catch(console.error)
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi Malik Lahlou there's something wrong with the `client.on('message',async message =>{` it's missing a parenthesis, thanks for the help btw

Comment: Lol i didn't realise, here it's fixed :3

Comment: Hello again @Malik Lahlou, an error have occurred `client.login(process.env.token);` and error is: `SyntaxError:  client.login(process.env.token` and I really appreciate your kindness for helping me :D

Comment: I really can't help you throught this problem with just this incomplete lign of error, if you want help, ask a new question on the discord.js tag (there's a link in the bottom of this page named "Ask your own question" :D !